Eevee shader is still compiling unconnected nodes?
So I made a complicated stylized material node tree in eevee. It does everything I need, but it consists of a huge number of nodes, so it takes quite a long time for blender to re-compile the shader whenever a change is made and it slows my viewport down when in rendered view (which I need to work in to see lighting in shots).
I figured to make it faster while I work, I will just plug in a second simpler node tree that just gives me the basic lighting info I need to work and test things, and then when I'm ready to do the final render I'll plug the complicated one back in.
So I did that, and to my surprise, the much simpler node tree still takes a long time to compile even with all the complex nodes now totally unconnected from the material output. To get the speed I expected I actually had to either mute or delete the complex node tree from the editor, even though it was not connected to anything. This would indicate to me that Eevee's shader compiling process is still having to use resources compiling nodes even when they aren't feeding into the render, which is obviously inefficient and unnecessary.
Is my assessment correct? Is that how Eevee works? If so....why?

sorry, but how shall we know if you don't show us your nodetree?

I'm pretty sure Blender doesn't compile nodes that aren't necessary for the active "Material Output" node.
Here is how it works:

Blender checks which node is connected to the active "Material Output" node.
Blender "runs" the node and check if there are nodes connected to this node
Blender "runs" these nodes, and if there are other nodes connected to them, it "runs" them too, and so on.

Therefore, Blender does not compile nodes that are not connected to the main node tree.
But, there are some very heavy nodes even if they are single on the node trees, and there are links between nodes that slow down rendering of the viewport as well.
For further help, it would be great if you could provide your full node tree, both simple and complex.
Edit: Maybe your simple node isn't heavy at all, and you just assume it's slow, but it's actually around the average Eevee shader rendering speed on your machine, try experimenting with some very simple Eevee shaders and see if it's about as slow. If so, maybe your machine is too slow for real-time lighting.
